# Rails Postgres fe_sendauth: no password supplied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been stuck with the following issue, which is popular question that was asked multiple times but none has worked for me. I see the following error when trying to `rake db:create` or `rails s`:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (fe_sendauth: no password supplied)`

I tried to create a new DB user but my `psql` fails with the following error:

```
Password for user <root_username>:
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<root_username>"
```

I've updated my `pg_hba.conf` file to use the `trust` method as suggested by many answers:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             <root_username>                           trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Finally, this is what my `database.yml` file looks like:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: datab_development
  #username: datab
  #host: localhost
```

I am using OSX 11 (Big Sur). Been hitting walls since this morning, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to restart or reload the database after changing the pg_hba.conf.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks, I actually restarted pgsql by running `brew services reload postgresql` post updating the conf file. Still having this issue.

Comment: Maybe a reload failed for some reason.  A restart is more definitive.  Better yet, stop it, verify it is down, then start it again.  That guards against there being multiple servers and you confusing which is which.  Also look in the log files to see if it processed the reload/restart.

Comment: @jjanes I tried killing all porstgres processes and restarting the server. I still see the error ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (fe_sendauth: no password supplied) -- which is also what I see in the logs :( 

Any thoughts on what I might be missing? Could I do a complete cleanup of all pgsql binaries and reinstall them (as I don't remember the password that I might have given when I first installed pgsql)